How can I implement the --trace flag in a custom Capistrano task?
I have a custom task that calls some very noisy  build tasks:
task :build_release do                                                                  
   SSHKit.config.command_map.prefix[:mix].unshift("#{fetch(:asdf_wrapper_path)}")        
  SSHKit.config.default_env[:MIX_ENV] = 'prod'                                          
                                                                                        
  on roles(:app) do |host|                                                              
    within release_path do                                                              
      execute(:mix, 'deps.get --only prod >dev/null')                                  
      execute(:mix, 'compile >/dev/null')                                               
      execute(:mix, 'assets.deploy >/dev/null')                                         
      execute(:mix, 'phx.gen.release >/dev/null')                                       
      execute(:mix, 'release >/dev/null')                                               
    end                                                                                 
  end                                                                                   
end        

The out put is much nicer when I send the out put from those mix tasks to /dev/null but now I won't be able to debug it without editing the script.
Is there a way to suppress the output unless the --trace flag is active? I'd like to do this the official way rather than just hacking something together.

You can check Rake.application.options.trace. It's actually a rake thing (remember, Capistrano is a rake wrapper!)
task :check_trace do
  puts "Tracing is #{Rake.application.options.trace ? "on" : "off"}"
end

❯ rake check_trace
Tracing is off
❯ rake check_trace --trace
** Invoke check_trace (first_time)
** Execute check_trace
Tracing is on

